# implementing opmodes in java encryption program dealing with both DES and AES

Tags: java

I have the code provided which works with ECB but I need to be able to also implement CBC, CFB, OFB, and CTR. If I can get these modes working, then I can complete my project by testing error propagation, and pattern preservation. I currently have the DES version for you to view, but ideally, i should be able to make slight alterations to make it AES supported as well.

Coding various entry level projects and a few security related projects, but no prior encryption experience.

```
   import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64DecoderStream;
    import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64EncoderStream;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    //import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DES {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strEnc = "01 02 03 04 05 06 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f";

    try {

    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey myKey = kg.generateKey();
    Cipher enc, des;
    enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    des = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

    // initialize the ciphers with the given key
    enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey);

    //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.println("Please enter your message: ");
    byte[] messageUtf8 = strEnc.getBytes("UTF8");

    System.out.println("Message [Byte Format} : " + messageUtf8);
    //System.out.println("Message: " + new String(messageUtf8));

    byte[] encMessage = enc.doFinal(messageUtf8);
    encMessage = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(encMessage);
    String encMsg = new String(encMessage);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Message: " + encMsg);

    // Decryption

    // decode with base64 to get bytes
    byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(encMsg.getBytes());

    byte[] decMessageUtf8 = des.doFinal(dec);

    String decMsg = new String(decMessageUtf8);   
    System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " +decMsg );

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    }
```

Expected results would to provide out put like this for each mode:

```
Message [Byte Format} : [B@7bb11784
Encrypted Message: dk2TnVfLHZf4p9o7fa00XjVaGenbiIItrCHhhA/UbjDcvf+E2Av5pw==
Decrypted Message: 01 02 03 04 05 06 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
```

However, I am getting these messages when trying to change modes:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:469)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineInit(DESCipher.java:186)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
    at DES.main(DES.java:30)
```